# FCEUX emulator doesn't show the tools menu

Tags: ubuntu, menu, emulation, bots

I have the FCEUX emulator 2.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, the problem is it doesn't show the tools menu:
[image]
As it should have:

[image]

I need the tools menu to get the RAM values for a bot I am creating.
Could someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no tools menu in the linux version of FCEUX. There are no tools. Learn to use wine and use the windows version.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tools menu in the linux version HOWEVER, you can still access the cheats interface by pressing "F1" while playing.

If you want other features beyond cheat interface then you might have to use the windows version :(
If you want the cheat interface, keep reading

The Linux cheat interface is command line only (no UI).

Here is how it works:

1. Make sure you start FCEUX from a terminal
2. While playing the game press F1
3. In the terminal you should see something like that

```
     1) List Cheats
     2) New Cheats...
     D) Display Menu
     X) Return to Previous

     Command >
```

Your game will be frozen while this menu is shown. You can press X to return back to your game.

Enter `2` to access the cheat functions, you should see output like that

```
1) Add Cheat
2) Reset Search
3) Do Search
4) Set Original to Current
5) Unhide Excluded
6) Show Results
7) Add Game Genie Cheat
8) Add PAR Cheat
D) Display Menu
X) Return to Previous
```

First you select `2` to reset the search function then you can select `3` to search for the value and you can enter `6` to view search result.

Of course first search would return lot of result so after you do that you press `X` twice to return back to the game, play a little bit then press `F1` again, choose `2` again (for new cheats) and perform anther search (without resetting this time!!).

repeat unit you find the value you are looking for